# Form that States Homework for Today

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

I am trying to program a thing where when I fill in the form and press the button "Submit Homework", it will display all my homework for today. This works, but however, it only displays the first form lines.

Any suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<center>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%"><col width="15%"><col width="55%"><col width="30%"><center><tr>
<th>Subject</th>
    <th>Name of Assignment</th>
    <th>Amount of Time</th></tr>

<tr><td>
<center><select id="Subject1">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td>
<td><center><input type="text" id="as1" size="45"></center></td>
<td><center><input type="number" id="time1" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>
</center>
<tr><td>
<center><select id="Subject2">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td><td><center><input type="text" id="as2" size="45"></center></td><td><center><input type="number" id="time2" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>
</center>
<tr><td>
<center><select id="Subject3">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td><td><center><input type="text" id="as3" size="45"></center></td><td><center><input type="number" id="time4" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>
</center>
<tr><td>
<center><select id="Subject4">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td><td><center><input type="text" id="as4" size="45"></center></td><td><center><input type="number" id="time4" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>
</center>
<tr><td>
<center><select id="Subject5">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td>
<td><center><input type="text" id="as5" size="45"></center></td><td><center><input type="number" id="time5" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>
<tr><td>

<center><select id="Subject6">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td><td><center><input type="text" id="as6" size="45"></center></td><td><center><input type="number" id="time6" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>

<tr><td>

<center><select id="Subject7">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td><td><center><input type="text" id="as7" size="45"></center></td><td><center><input type="number" id="time7" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>
<tr><td>

<center><select id="Subject8">
  <option value="select">Select One</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
  <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  <option value="Science">Science</option>
<option value="Math">Math</option>
  <option value="World Cultures">World Cultures</option>
  <option value="ELA">ELA</option>
<option value="Orchestra">Orchestra</option>
<option value="Contest Math">Contest Math</option>
<option value="divider">-----------------------</option>
<option value="Piano">Piano</option>
<option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
</select></center></td><td><center><input type="text" id="as8" size="45"></center></td><td><center>
<input type="number" id="time8" min= “5” max= “1000” size="16"></center></td></tr>

</center>

</table>
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()" class='button'>Submit Homework</button>
<style>
.button {
   border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
   background: #3e779d;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#65a9d7), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7 0%, #3e779d 100%);
   padding: 9.5px 19px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
   -moz-border-radius: 13px;
   border-radius: 13px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
   color: #06426c;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: helvetica, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.button:hover {
   border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
   text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
   background: #3e779d;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#65a9d7), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7, #3e779d);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #65a9d7 0%, #3e779d 100%);
   color: #fff;
   }
.button:active {
   text-shadow: #1e4158 0 1px 0;
   border: 1px solid #0a3c59;
   background: #65a9d7;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#3e779d));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d 0%, #65a9d7 100%);
   color: #fff;
   }
</style>
<br><br>
<h4 id="aa"></h4>
<h4 id="bb"></h4>
<h4 id="aaa"></h4>
<h4 id="dd"></h4>
<h4 id="ee"></h4>
<h4 id="ff"></h4>
<h4 id="gg"></h4>
<h4 id="hh"></h4>

<style>
h4 {
    font-size: 110%;
}
th {
    font-size: 150%;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementById("Subject1").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("as1").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("time1").value;
    document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = a + ": " + b + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + c + " minutes";

var d = document.getElementById("Subject2").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("as2").value;
    var f = document.getElementById("time2").value;
    document.getElementById("bb").innerHTML = d + ": " + e + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + f + " minutes";

var g = document.getElementById("Subject3").value;
    var h = document.getElementById("as3").value;
    var i = document.getElementById("time3").value;
    document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML = g + ": " + h + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + i + " minutes";

var j = document.getElementById("Subject4").value;
    var k = document.getElementById("as4").value;
    var l = document.getElementById("time4").value;
    document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = j + ": " + k + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + l + " minutes";

var m = document.getElementById("Subject5").value;
    var n = document.getElementById("as5").value;
    var o = document.getElementById("time5").value;
    document.getElementById("ee").innerHTML = m + ": " + n + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + o + " minutes";

var p = document.getElementById("Subject6").value;
    var q = document.getElementById("as6").value;
    var r = document.getElementById("time6").value;
    document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = p + ": " + q + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + r + " minutes";

var s = document.getElementById("Subject6").value;
    var t = document.getElementById("as6").value;
    var u = document.getElementById("time6").value;
    document.getElementById("gg").innerHTML = s + ": " + t + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + u + " minutes";

var v = document.getElementById("Subject8").value;
    var w = document.getElementById("as8").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("time8").value;
    document.getElementById("hh").innerHTML = v + ": " + w + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + x + " minutes";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ID time4 is duplicated and time3 does not exist. To find errors like this open your browsers console log and you will see the error.

Inspect Element > console

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
<input type="number" id="time3" min= "5" max= "1000" size="16"/>
```